# Advice for using backbone BUI or jQueryMobile

Tags: jquery-mobile, backbone.js, marionette, backbone-views

I believe that both [backbone BUI](https://github.com/tonydspaniard/BUI)! and jQueryMobile can be used for designing UI's for backbone mobile app.

But can anyone please tell me preferring which one is good. Actually i want specifically Carousel view to be designed. So can anyone please tell me making carousel view with backbone BUI is easy or jQuerymobile.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's no carousel component, as far as I know, in jQuery mobile. As for the project you link to, there doesn't appear to be any documentation so it's not easy to tell whether it has a carousel component or not. But the lack of documentation and the fact that there have been no commits for a year would make make me wary of using it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Have been using jQuery-mobile and happy with it.
You can take a look  plugin like [`diapo`](http://www.pixedelic.com/plugins/diapo) to provide 'Carousel'